# Voltage drop in a switching circuit with two storage elements

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, capacitor, inductor

There is a switch between Vs and V1 that closes the circuit at t=0. The resulting circuit is shown below. When analyzing this circuit for t>0, why is the voltage drop across Vs and V1 not zero? When finding the second order differential equation, we cannot treat v1 as equivalent to Vs. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't meaningfully talk about V1 without referring to its reference node (0 volts). If that reference node is the negative end of source Vs then, V1 will equal Vs. If that reference node is somewhere else (like the junction of R1 and R2) then they won't be equal.

> *Why?*

- Vs is a source and is fully defined as to where it connects in the circuit.
- V1 is a label attached to a node and needs a reference node to numerically define it.